# How to thread-safe function that adds elements to array?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, stdthread

I wrote the following function that accepts an object (`element`), makes space for it in an existing vector (`elements`) and updates the vector by adding the new object:

```
void addElement(const ElementType& element) {
    if (numElements == elements.size()) {
        elements.resize(boost::extents[numElements+1]);
    }

    elements[numElements] = element;

    numElements++;
}
```

How can I make it thread-safe for MPI? To my understanding, every thread knows what the size of `elements` is, therefore I don't see why this function would not be thread-safe. `numElements` is initialized to zero outside this function and is the size of the `elements` vector.

Edit: I am using the function as written above and mtx lock and unlock as follows, but still the final `elements` vector contains data from the first rank only.

```
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) schedule(static)
    for (long n0 = mgr->startN0; n0 < mgr->startN0 + mgr->localN0; n0++) {
      for (int n1 = 0; n1 < Ν; n1++) {
        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < Ν; n2++) {
          ElementType element;
          std::mutex mtx;
            for(int i=0;i<g_field[n0][n1][n2];i++){
              ... do stuff with element ...
              mtx.lock();
              #pragma omp critical
              addElement(element);
              mtx.unlock();}
       }
     }
   }
```

Edit: For speed reasons I had to change the function and its use slightly:

```
void addElements_MPI(std::vector<ElementType> new_batch,std::mutex& mtx) {

  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); 
  elements.resize(boost::extents[elements.num_elements()+new_batch.size()]); 

  std::copy(new_batch.begin(), new_batch.end(), elements.begin()+numElements); 

  numElements += new_batch.size();
}
```

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::vector<ElementType> all_elements;
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(3) schedule(static)
    for (long n0 = mgr->startN0; n0 < mgr->startN0 + mgr->localN0; n0++) {
      for (int n1 = 0; n1 < Ν; n1++) {
        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < Ν; n2++) {

          ElementType element;

            for(int i=0;i<g_field[n0][n1][n2];i++){
              ... do stuff with element ...
              mtx.lock();
              #pragma omp critical
              all_elements.push_back(element);
              mtx.unlock();}
       }
     }
   }
 mtx.lock();
 #pragma omp critical
 addElement_MPI(all_elements,mtx);
 mtx.unlock();
```

Comment: 2 (or more) threads can `addElement` in the same time. To protect this you need to use `std::mutex`

Comment: What is the link between MPI and thread safety?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's see when the data race happens:

- two or more threads access the same memory location concurrently
- at least one of the accesses is for writing
- threads are not using any exclusive locks to control their accesses to that memory

In your case, one thread can add the element while other thread is reading `elements`. Also, multiple threads can add new elements at the same time. To control their accesses, you should lock the shared resource i.e. `elements`.

**How do I lock shared resource in C++?**

In C++, you can use [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) to protect shared data from being simultaneously accessed by multiple threads. When the `std::mutex` is locked by one thread, other threads cannot access the shared resource. Once `std::mutex` is unlocked, other threads can access the resource. You can use `std::mutex::lock` and `std::mutex::unlock` like:

```cpp
std::mutex mtx;
ElementsType elements;

...
mtx.lock();

// only one thread accesses this part at a time
// work with elements

mtx.unlock();
```

**Developers often forgot something...**

Since developers often forgot something... like unlocking the `std::mutex` which is locked... C++ provides [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) (in case of C++11) and [`std::scoped_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/scoped_lock) (in case of C++17). You can think of `std::lock_guard` and `std::scoped_lock` as some sort of wrappers that take `std::mutex` instance as constructor's parameter and lock that `std::mutex` instance in constructor. When `std::lock_guard` or `std::scoped_lock` instance is being destructed, `std::mutex` instance is automatically unlocked.

```cpp
void addElement(const ElementType& element) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx); // similar to mtx.lock()

    if (numElements == elements.size()) {
        elements.resize(boost::extents[numElements+1]);
    }

    elements[numElements] = element;

    numElements++;

    // no need for mtx.unlock() since lock instance is now destructed and mutex is automatically unlocked
}
```

**EDIT**

Since `std::mutex` is some sort of a communication channel between all the threads, all threads should share the same `std::mutex` instance, i.e. the same `std::mutex` instance should be visible to all the threads.

In case below (which I took from the updated question):

```cpp
for (int n2 = 0; n2 < Ν; n2++) {
    ElementType element;
    std::mutex mtx;
    for(int i=0;i<g_field[n0][n1][n2];i++){
         // ... do stuff with element ...
         mtx.lock();
         #pragma omp critical
         addElement(element);
         mtx.unlock();}
    }
}
```

`std::mutex` is being created N times and each thread creates its own `std::mutex` instance which doesn't make any sense because than they cannot communicate with each other. Instead, one `std::mutex` instance should be visible to all the threads just as the `elements` are visible to all the threads.

Comment: (upvoted) But I think that some explanation to the answer about **when** the data-race happens, and about the `std::lock_guard` and `std::scoped_lock`.

Comment: @Kerek thanks, i will update my answer with those suggestions

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer, much appreciated. I tried using lock and unlock but still the final vector contains data from the first rank still. I have modified my initial question accordingly in case anyone has time to review it.

Comment: @Choumbie you missed one thing... you define `std::mutex` in the function itself, so every thread has its own `std::mutex` but all threads should share the same `std::mutex` because it is some sort of a communication channel between all the threads. I suggest you define global `std::mutex` instance visible to all the threads, it can be defined where the `elements` are defined.

Comment: @NutCracker Thanks for updating your answer. I had to slightly change the function and its call for speed purposes (updated question) but in both functions (`addElements` and `addElements_MPI`), the threads reach the call, but never actually enter it. I also tried with lock/unlock explicitly, but the issue persists. I have to pass `mtx` as an argument as you can see above. Is there some problem with that perhaps?

Comment: @Choumbie There should be no problem with passing `std::mutex` by reference but you might complicate your code too much with it. Can we somehow get into the chat maybe? I am not sure if SO provides chat option unless there is too much comments...

Comment: @NutCracker I found your email on your blog. Sent you a message there!